# Dont get css in gtk3 with glade to work

Tags: css, c, gtk3, glade

I want to load a glade-file and change the color of all toggle-buttons ( class "GtkToggleButton" , I want to change the "pressed" color) The toggle-button is one of many sub-sub-element in the glade-file.
Here the C-code-snipped I use to load the .css and the .glade:

```
void on_minute_pressed(GtkWidget *button)
{
    GtkCssProvider *cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider,"./test.css",NULL);
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "minute_dialog.glade", NULL);
    GtkWidget       *window= GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "MinuteWizard"));
    gtk_window_set_transient_for (window,main_window);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider(gtk_widget_get_style_context(window),cssProvider,GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    g_object_unref(builder);
}
```

And here the .css I currently use:

```
.button {
  padding: 30;
  background-color: shade (@bg_color, 55);
}

togglebutton entry {
  color: 900185;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #0274d9;
}
```

What currently happens: The new window load's fine, but it seems like it does not matter what I write into the .css, it does not change the look of the window-elements. I can see that the .css is loaded, because I get warnings like:

> Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: test.css:2:13: Not using units is
>   deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

What is wrong ? Do I need to apply the .css to each sub-widged separately?

Comment: The `Not using units is deprecated` comes from old CSS files, where some size are just specified by a number, such as `border=1`. Present gtk versions require those to be specified as `1px`. Mind, if your theme is so old, you will probably run into problems with gtk newer than 3.20! It should not influence your main problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found out myself what was the problem:

According to the documentation of [gtk_style_context_add_provider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-provider) css providers are not inherited to the children style contexts.

So either one needs to apply the css to each single widget, or use [gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-provider-for-screen) to change the css of the whole screen:

```
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

Comment: I'm suffering from same problem, where did you find "Currently CSS providers are not inherited to the children style contexts." ?

Comment: From the official doc of the method: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-provider ... I'll add the info to my answer

Answer (score 1):

A list of suggestions too long to put as comments:

- Could it be that you have another version of your theme's CSS installed in `~/.themes`? If so, that theme will be superseding the theme in `/usr/share/themes`.
- Since XDG, there is yet another possibility for the location of the CSS: From the [dev documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` below is typically `~/.config`):

> In addition, certain files will be read when GTK+ is initialized.
>   First, the file $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/gtk.css is loaded if it
>   exists. Then, GTK+ loads the first existing file among
>   XDG_DATA_HOME/themes/theme-name/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css,
>   $HOME/.themes/theme-name/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css,
>   $XDG_DATA_DIRS/themes/theme-name/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css and
>   DATADIR/share/themes/THEME/gtk-VERSION/gtk.css, where THEME is the
>   name of the current theme (see the #GtkSettings:gtk-theme-name
>   setting), DATADIR is the prefix configured when GTK+ was compiled
>   (unless overridden by the GTK_DATA_PREFIX` environment variable), and
>   VERSION is the GTK+ version number. If no file is found for the
>   current version, GTK+ tries older versions all the way back to 3.0.

- Another solution for you might be to use the [`GtkCssProvider`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) interface for specific widget styles.

An interesting reference is [`Installing, Obtaining, and Making GTK Themes`](http://www.linux.org/threads/installing-obtaining-and-making-gtk-themes.8463/)

Comment: I dont have the folder "~/.themes". I have "~/config/gtk-3.0" and "~/config/gtk-2.0", but inside is no "gtk.css". $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set, so I quess the default will be used. So I quess I just use the default-theme.

Comment: I already use the GtkCssProvider in the C-code (see code above) .. is there a different one for specific widgets ? ... actually I dont want to build up a whole theme .. I just want to have more contrast between "pressed" and "not pressed" of the toggle button, no matter which theme is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```css
.button {
  padding: 30px; /* px unit added */
  background-color: shade (@bg_color, 55);
}
    
.togglebutton .entry {
  color: #900185; /* # added */
}
    
.button:active {
  background-color: #0274d9;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">aaaa</button>
<button class="button togglebutton"><span class="entry">aaaa</span></button>
```

Comment: Buttons still look the same :( .. I as well tried with color: red / color: blue, but it does not change anything.

Comment: I've updated the snippet. You have forgot `.` before class names

Comment: Thanks for the "." hint, but still nothing .. seems to be a gtk3 related problem.

Comment: This answer looks like it has assumed the question is about HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class name in 'style classes' for the widget in Glade:
[glade_screenshot_button_attr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc79h.png)